# How to test a number against two conditions simultaneously with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I'm having an issue making my loop test against two conditions simultaneously.

```
for (var result = 0; result <= 100; result ++)
  if (result % 3 == 0)
    console.log ('Fizz');
  else if (result % 5 == 0)
    console.log ('Buzz');
   else console.log (result);
```

How can I build a third condition that tests if result is divisible by 3 AND 5?

```
else if ( result % 5 == 0 && result % 3 == 0)
    console.log ('FizzBuzz');
  else console.log (result);
```

This was my solution and 'FizzBuzz' didn't make it the console at all! Why didn't that solution work?

Comment: you don't need to check it against `result % 5 == 0 && result % 3 == 0`. actually you must not do it! it is a tricky task and solution not so simple as you can expect. check out solution beneath.

Comment: this task not about simply putting `fizzbuzz` stuff into console, but about applying composition concept in javascript but you are not combining objects you combining `if statements` to build more complex statement.

Answer (score 4):

The order matters!

```
if (result % 5 == 0 && result % 3 == 0)
  console.log ('FizzBuzz');
else if (result % 3 == 0)
  console.log ('Fizz');
else if (result % 5 == 0)
  console.log ('Buzz');
else console.log (result);
```

When `result` is both a multiple of 3 AND a multiple of 5, the following both hold:

- `result` is a multiple of 3
- `result` is a multiple of 5

So if you check `result % 5 == 0 && result % 3 == 0` in the `else` part, it will never be true.

You might also consider nested conditionals:

```
if (result % 3 == 0)
  if (result % 5 == 0)
    console.log ('FizzBuzz');
  else
    console.log ('Fizz');
else if (result % 5 == 0)
  console.log ('Buzz');
else console.log (result);
```

Comment: Oh wow Oriol, you absolutely rule, that fixed my problem immediately!

Comment: @IslamIbakaev How are you going to know if it's a multiple of both, then?

Comment: A slight semantic point (sorry!): checking that `result % 5 === 0 && result % 3 ===  0` in the `else` part doesn't mean it's not true, it's just that the condition is never reached, and so never checked, because both the previous conditions are also true. I'm genuinely sorry, it really is a minor point... 

Comment: @DavidThomas The condition would be reached when `result` is not a multiple of 3 nor 5, and would always be false. Of course the condition would be true if `result` is a multiple of 3 and 5, but in that case it won't be reached, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your last code fragment is missing a bit, but I'd assume it's because you're testing your `AND` statement in an `else if` block.

You're saying

```
if result is a multiple of 3 print fizz
otherwise (not a multiple of 3), if result is a multiple of 5 print buzz
otherwise (not a multiple of 3 nor 5), if result is a multiple of 3 and 5 print fizzbuzz
```

Obviously, result will never be all of the conditions in part 3 since it can't be

```
NOT 3x 
NOR 5y 
AND 3x 
AND 5y
```

at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea but the wrong order.
Since the single statements:

```
if(result % x == 0)
```

will return before the combined if() statement, and so the condition never gets that far. This worked for me:

```
for(var result=0; result <=15; result++) 
  if(result % 5 == 0 && result % 3 ==0) 
      console.log('FizBuzz');
    else if(result % 3 == 0)
      console.log('Fizz')
  else if(result % 5 == 0)
    console.log('Buzz');
  else
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the catch of the task - you don't need to test against `(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0)`

```js
function fizzBuzzTest() {
  "use strict";

  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    let str = "";

    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      str = "Fizz";
    }
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
      str += "Buzz";
    }
    if (!str) {
      str = i;
    }

    console.log(str);
  }
}
fizzBuzzTest();
```

Comment: you guys before giving a minus better check how it works

Comment: If you want us to "*check how it works*" include a Snippet in your answer so we can *see* it working.

Comment: but why giving a minus before checking it?

Comment: Because it intuitively feels wrong? I have no idea, I've not voted either way but I can see that it *does* work, even though it's written differently than I'd do it myself, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: this is a task that you can came across on code interview. And the tricky part is that you must not check against (3 and 5). this task is not so simply as you guys expect it to be.